# adist for groups of words

Tags: r, distance

I have a table like:

```
df<-data.frame(palabra=c('ani', 'anib', 'alop', 'alope','ber', 'beren'))
```

And I need to create a distance matrix for groups of words, grouped by their 1st character.

To do so I add:

```
df$letra<-substring(df$palabra,1,1)
```

Now I need to apply adist function for each group. Just to put an example of adist:

```
adist(df$palabra, costs=list(insertions=1, deletions=1, substitutions=2))
```

How can I create one table of distance for each group?

Comment: Do you mean apply the adist function only for the words that start with "a" and create a table, then apply it only on words starting with "b" and so on and so forth? In the end are you expecting as many tables as there are distinct first letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple combination of `lapply` and `split` will give you want you want:

```
#split is used to create two data frames; one for group a and one
#for groupb b
#lapply will apply the adist function to each of the groups
lapply(split(df, df$letra), function(x) {
  adist(x$palabra, costs=list(insertions=1, deletions=1, substitutions=2))
})
```

Output:

```
$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    5    6
[2,]    1    0    6    7
[3,]    5    6    0    1
[4,]    6    7    1    0

$b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    2
[2,]    2    0
```